# Creating Link for a spefic word under pdf using node js code

Tags: node.js

I have a pdf file for ex: pdf/output/merged.pdf under this location, now I want to create a hyperlink for a particular text in that pdf. How can I achieve this using node js

Comment: Please let me know if you responsible to maintain that PDF or is the file provided by end users? If you are responsible for the maintenance of the PDF, then you can create [destinations](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html). Otherwise, if you don't have control over the pdf, you can convert it into HTML and append the Hyperlink through script, for this, you can find libraries like pdh2html.

Comment: Yes, I have control over pdf after converting pdf to HTML how to add hyperlink through script using node js could you please provide with dummy example for appending hyperlink to html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.